# Blue/green deployment - AWS Cloudfront with ELB as custom origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

I have following configuration:

`Cloudfront - ELB - AutoScalingGroup - EC2s`

- Cloudfront serves `file-[hash].js` files (with chunkhash in their names) from custom origin (ELB).
- EC2s serve the `file-[hash].js` files for Cloudfront plus dynamically generated `index.html` file that points to appropriate `.js` file at Cloudfront.
- ELB has connection draining enabled.

Everything works fine until a Cloudformation deployment with a changed asset is triggered (let's say from `file-1.js` to `file-2.js`) - when the new version is being switched on, there is a short time window when browser gets the new `index.html` file pointing to `file-2.js`, but when it tries to download `file-2.js` it gets 404 from Cloudfront, thus showing an error to the user.

I understand this is because how blue/green deployment works - i.e. there is a time when two versions of the application works simultaneously and ELB can redirect one request to the new version (request for `index.html` from the browser) and second one to the old version (request for `file-2.js` from Cloudfront).

[Cloudfront docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CustomOriginBestPractices.html) say that you should "host and serve the same content on all servers.", but how can I achieve that during the deployment? Is it possible to enforce that only single version of application is accessible through ELB at any given time, so that Cloudfront never gets 404 for the new assets?

If not, are there any other options to solve this, apart from switching from custom origin to S3? (would like to avoid it due to deployment / maintenance complexity)

Note switching from update policy AutoScalingRollingUpdate to AutoScalingReplacingUpdate did not help:

```
 asg:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    CreationPolicy:
      ResourceSignal:
        Count:
          Ref: 2
        Timeout: PT10M
    UpdatePolicy:
      AutoScalingReplacingUpdate:
        WillReplace: true
```

Comment: I tried solving this with ELB session affinity, but it was too complex to propagate this affinity through CloudFront, which will cache the responses with an AWSELB cookie but not serve the same cookie to further hits (because ELBs specify `Cache-Control: no-cache=set-cookie`)

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: @Andy, no, I'm now always serving static content from S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution to this is to keep the static .js files in S3, and maintain previous versions alongside new ones during publish of new applications.

CloudFront will serve the static content from S3, and the dynamic content from EC2.

Publish the static content to S3 first, then start transition.

In this case, the dynamically generated index page would refer to one S3 bucket in the old version, and another in the new. Since both resources always resolve in S3 there will be no 404.